# Get $post->ID from a URL

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I have a custom post type called **music**. I have created a custom template as a normal page to show some stats for the musicians. I have a page where they can see all their songs and have added a stats link. The stats link automatically generates URL based on that custom post.

An example URL looks like this `https://domain.com/song-stats/?pid=17643`

The 17643 in the URL is for a specific song in the custom music post type.   The following code works fine on this template page.

```
<?php $key_1_values = get_post_meta(17643, '_song_name', true ); ?>
```

Your song is called `<?php echo $key_1_values ?>`.

I am trying to dynamically generate the 17643 to be whatever number is in the URL. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't know if I understood exactly. but couldn't you just use the `$_GET['pid']` variable? Like `$key_1_values = get_post_meta((int) $_GET['pid'], '_song_name', true );`

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is old question, but maybe this will help

```
url_to_postid( string $url )
```

[WP Code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/url_to_postid/)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for are the `get_queried_object()` functions. You can simply get the id as such:

```
$post_id = $get_queried_object_id;
```

OR

```
$post_id = get_the_id();
```

Or maybe you simply mean `$_GET['pid']` ?

Answer (score -1):

I don't Know if I understand the question correctly, but if I do I think this can help you:

This is not tested yet and is assuming url's for music posts have always the same format and the code is placed somewhere in the template for music posts.

```
<?php
     $url = get_post_permalink(); //Get the url of the current post
     $substring_start_pos = strpos($url, 'pid=') + 4; //Find the position in $url string where the url number starts
     $url_number = substr($url, $substring_start_pos); //Extract the substring form the start position to the end of the url string
     $key_1_values = get_post_meta($url_number, '_song_name', true );
     echo "Your song is called $key_1_values"; 
?>
```